# Triggering click event inside my .click callback causes "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I couldn't get any possible reason as to why is this happening.
I have a button which opens a bootstrap popup. But before opening the modal I need to alter some of my variables, So I am triggering a click event on hidden button which opens the bootstrap modal.
HTML looks something like-

```
<div id="visible-button">
   <span class="hidden" id="open-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popup-modal"></span>
</div>
```

And the js code is something like-

```
$('#visible-button').click(function(){
   //perform data manipulation
   $('#open-modal').trigger('click');
});
```

But this produces

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

If I edit the code to

```
$('#visible-button').click(function(){
   //perform data manipulation
   setTimeout(function(){
     $('#open-modal').trigger('click');
   }, 500);
});
```

The modal keeps opening and dissappearing for ever.
What is exactly happening here? I have triggered click event in the past too but have never faced such a scenario.
Thanks for the help in Advance.

Comment: Looks like my HTML is causing the problem here. Triggering click on child element induces click on the parent element too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As `open-modal` is wrapped inside `visible-button`, triggering a click on `open-modal` is equivalent to triggering a click on `visible-button`. So when you click on visible button, onclick event of `visible-button` gets triggered which intern clicks on `visible-button` again, and it gets into a infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks @Ravikiran kalal. It helped me.

Answer (score 3):

This will prevent the error. The reason for the error is you're clicking the same parent recursively. Having the button and the modal separately will fix the problem.

```
<div id="visible-button"></div>

<span class="hidden" id="open-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popup-modal"></span>
```

Comment: How can I make it work if case I wanted to use the same HTML?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the click events are being called recursively without an end. Do you have any callback function for the click event for `open-modal` `<span>` ? If so, please share it.

Comment: No, I don't have any callback for open-modal or <span>

Answer (score 0):

Its due to event propagation from child element to parent element. When you click `<span>` (child element) it propogate event to parent `<div>`.

You have binded event when parent click it click on child.  so in propofgation of click event goes in infinite loop so you have to stop propogation by `e.preventDefault();` or `return false;` on end of click event function

```
$('#visible-button').click(function(e){
   //perform data manipulation
   $('#open-modal').trigger('click');
   return false;
});

$('[data-target="#popup-modal"]').click(function(e){
   $("#popup-modal").modal();
   return false;
});
```

Comment: This also produces the same behaviour.