# JQuery click() - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.link-check').on("click", function(e){ 
        $(this).find("input").click();
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link-check">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> Check
        </label>
    </a>
```

When I click on a link or directly on an input it prints, constantly, in the console `Maximum call stack size exceeded` and the page is blocked.

If I execute `$('.link-check')` and `$('.link-check').find("input")` in the console, it returns just one element, in both cases.

Why do I get that error?

Comment: **Your HTML is invalid. Interactive elements like `a`, `button`, `label` cannot have interactive content.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Triggering click event inside my .click callback causes "Maximum call stack size exceeded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524968/triggering-click-event-inside-my-click-callback-causes-maximum-call-stack-size)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Similar to that duplicate, but worse.

Answer (score 2):

First of all:

**Your HTML is invalid. Interactive elements like `a`, `button`, `label` cannot have interactive content.** ***Your HTML cannot stay like that.***

---

Regarding your question: Congratulations, you've just created your (hopefully) first infinite loop!

`click` events by default *bubble* up the DOM, so your programmatic

```
$(this).find("input").click();
```

creates a `click` event on that `input` **which then bubbles up and triggers your listener on `$('.link-check').on("click"`**, which then clicks the inner `input`, which then triggers your click listener, and so on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on ... **You get the point.**

---

### Again: You cannot have HTML like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').on("click", function(e){ 
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Please try this code.

I think **event bubbling** is the problem here.

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're calling the click inside the onClick function, that triggers the function again and again and again...

It's called recursion and is a valid structure but you need to put some stop condition or your code will run eternally 'til you have an stack overflow on your memory;

see: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/recursion-in-javascript-1608032c7a1f/